# How to include local jars into gradle dependency reports?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, local

I have to use some proprietary libs in my project. They are connected with

```
implementation fileTree('lib') { include '*.jar' }
```

in my build.gradle and it works fine. But when i do

```
gradle dependencies
```

those jars are not listed in the output, but i'd like to see them there. Is there a way to add local jars in the gradle's dependency tree reports?

Answer (score 0):

probably not "really" what you want, but you always can just print the fileTree to stdout in a doLast { } on the dependencies task.

e.g. in kotlin build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
val dependencies by tasks.existing {
    doLast {
        val libsFiles = fileTree("libs").files
        if (libsFiles.isNotEmpty()) println("\nlocal jars in '${project.rootProject.projectDir}/libs'")
        libsFiles.forEach {
            println("+--- libs/${it.name}")
        }
    }
}
```